Crumpled Look After Rendering
I was trying to make a jet engine but encountered a baffling problem when I rendered.

One of the 28 fan blades looks kinda crumpled after finishing it's viewport render when it should be completely smooth as is in the viewport preview in the image below:

I tried recalculating normals to try fixing it but it didn't work.
How do I fix this?

Found out why:
when I used the spin tool on the blade to make it complete, I forgot to merge it. Found out after making a spin animation and it not being centered after centering origin.

Hi, Fin, ...Glad you found it!  Sounds like a simple slip-up, and you have  a fix without needing an answer.. either post a quick self answer, or we can close this one out.. whichever you prefer.

Stacked blades. When i used the spin tool i forgot to merge the stacked blades and it made the render glitch out a bit. So i just select all and merge by distance since they occupy the same coordinate in space.
